# kill function returning invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86

I am using `kill` function to `kill` a process. However, its returning -1 and `perror` shows "Invalid argument". Reading the manual of `kill`, it says this error occurs if wrong signal value is provided. I am passing `-9` or `SIGKILL`, like this `kill( SIGKILL, pid )`.

Then why is it giving invalid argument error. Note that the process who is calling the `kill` function is the child of the process that we are trying to kill.

Comment: From @CarlNorum's answer, it just seems that you invert your arguments...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`kill` takes its arguments the other way around.  From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill):

```
int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```

Since you're passing the PID in place of the signal number and vice-versa, it's pretty likely that at least one of them will be an invalid argument as `perror` is telling you.

Answer (score 2):

Your `kill( SIGKILL, pid );` should be `kill(pid, SIGKILL);`

`man 2 kill`